# Retrieve image from mvc using ImageSource.FromUri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms

I have mvc web api that post images. im trying to retrieve an image to my xamarin project using `ImageSource.FromUri`

Im totaly able to view this image in the web site. but not on my xamarin project.

what im i doing wrong i wonder. here is my code

> API that post the image

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetImage(string imagePath)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Actions.ImageRootPath, imagePath);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            return new EmptyResult();

        var stream= System.IO.File.OpenRead(path);

        return File(stream, "image/png");
    }
```

> xamarin xaml

```
    <Frame Style="{StaticResource FrameContainer}" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="150" CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Transparent">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Logo, Converter={StaticResource ImageSource}}" WidthRequest="200" />
                            <StackLayout  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource Form}" Padding="10,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource Header}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding TotalVideos}" IsVisible="{Binding TotalVideos, Converter={StaticResource StringNullOrEmpty}}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource UnderText}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
```

> ImageSource the converter

```
    if (value is string && value != null && value.ToString().Length >= 4 && !value.ToString().Contains("http"))
    {
        byte[] Base64Stream = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value.ToString());
        var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Base64Stream));
        return img;
    }
    else if (value is string && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value?.ToString() ?? "") && value.ToString().Contains("http"))
    {
        var uri = new Uri(value.ToString());

        return ImageSource.FromUri(uri);
        //var data = Helper.HttpHelper.GetImage(value.ToString());
        //return GetImage(key, data.ToArray());

    }
    else if (value is byte[])
    {
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(value as byte[]));
    }
    return ImageSource.FromFile("NoImage.png");
```

What i tried and worked but i dont like

This code below work but i have to download the image first using webclient

```
    var data = Helper.HttpHelper.GetImage(value.ToString());
    return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(data));
```

Here is the image url

```
http://youtubemanager.ddns.net/Youtube.Manager.API/Images/GetImage?imagePath=alen.toma%5Cc2e8bcaa-e258-453b-84c4-868d23b03848.png
```

Comment: if you just hardcode that url into the Image Source attribute does it work?

Comment: No the same issue, even without the converter i get the same result.

Comment: The Converter works with other url like youtube images, but not with the api i created. Im gussing that the API need to include something in the header but i dont know what.` File` should include all the necessary data. I even tried to write it down to response and inc all the header eg content type, length etc and still not working

Comment: @Alen, I try to use ImageSource.FromUri to display image, it works fine, and you also said that Helper.HttpHelper.GetImage works, so what is your problem?

Comment: Fromuri does not work. I have to download and convert the image to stream so it could work